# What bang / boom sounds do not invoke supersonic propagation?

Tags: acoustics

Explosions, supersonic booms, whiplash sounds are usually supersonic phenomenona.

What sort-of common bang / boom sounds are there that do not involve supersonic propagation ? Or is this a "wrong" question (why) ?

Comment: Should you distinguish between (1) objects like jets moving faster than the speed of sound, (2) air particles moving faster than the speed of sound, and (3) sound... moving faster than the speed of sound?

Comment: Whoops, should have read _not invoke supersonic propagation_...

Comment: Not quite a full answer, but wouldn't any recording of a sound involving a shockwave played back over a normal set of speakers be the same sound but without the supersonic shockwave?

Comment: Yeah, probably, that's also what I was thinking... the question would be - would the sounds be qualitatively indistinguishable, or would they just _sound_ like a boom ?